# Visualization of nested Piecewise output with a tree diagram (or something similar)

Tags: visualization, piecewise

I have outputs which are in the form of nested Piecewise functions and I want to represent these diagrammatically. There are multiple levels in general. A simple example with two levels is:

```
Piecewise[{{Piecewise[{{f = a, y > 0}, {f = b, y <= 0}}], z > 0}, {f = c, z <= 0}}]
```

where `y` and `z` are `Reals`. I would like to express this result as a tree diagram (or something similar), where vertices would be labeled by the conditions and leaves would be the values of `f`. How can I write a function which can turn this output into such a diagram?

Comment: Have you tried `TreeForm`?

Comment: `TreeForm` looks like it will be useful. Thank you @bill s

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to use [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html)

```
p = Piecewise[{{Piecewise[{{f = a, y > 0}, {f = b, y <= 0}}], z > 0}, 
  {f = c, z <= 0}}];

p2 = p // PiecewiseExpand;

p == p2 // Simplify

(*  True  *)

p2 // TreeForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
p = Piecewise[{{Piecewise[{{f = a, y > 0}, 
              {f = b, y <= 0}}], z > 0}, {f = c, z <= 0}}];
TreeForm[p]
```

[image]